# MongoDB Delete records where group by count

Tags: mongodb

I have a lot of records that contains duplicate addresses. Basically, I want to delete those records that has number of duplicate addresses more than 50 but less than 300.

This is how I get those records that I want to delete:

```
db.directories.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: { address: "$address" }, total: { $sum: 1 } } },
   { $match: { total: { $gt: 50, $lt: 300 } } },
   { $sort: { total: -1 } }
], { allowDiskUse: true });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the cursor method **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** to iterate the cursor returned from the **[`aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)** method and delete the documents using the [**`remove()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/) method, as in the following example:

```
var pipeline = [
   { $group: { _id: { address: "$address" }, total: { $sum: 1 } } },
   { $match: { total: { $gt: 50, $lt: 300 } } },
   { $sort: { total: -1 } }
];
var options = { allowDiskUse: true };
db.directories.aggregate(pipeline, options).forEach(function (doc){
    var query = {"address": doc._id.address};
    db.directories.remove(query);
});
```

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't delete anything. It took a long time to finish but the documents were still there.

Comment: @RazaFarooq My bad, the query to delete was wrong. It was `{"address": doc._id}` instead of `{"address": doc._id.address}`, the latter should work. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Thanks @chridam, I got it to work. I should have spotted this error.